# to be more responsive

Tags: parsing

> I think we need to recognize leaders when they reverse course **to be more responsive** to what public-health authorities say **is necessary to protect people**.

Source: Nature   [Chelsea Clinton urges global sharing of COVID vaccine technology](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-02164-8)

What is the subject of the sentence? Is "to be more responsive" the subject to the verb phrase "is necessary to protect people"?

Comment: The subject of the sentence is *I*. If it helps, the (that) is omitted which makes everything from "we need..." onwards a direct object clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is "I".

The structure of the sentence is "I[subject]  think [verb] "..." [Clausal complement of the verb 'think']

The subordinate clause "is necessary..." doesn't have an explicit subject.  Implicitly the subject is the pronoun "what".  Which refers, circularly to "the thing that is neccessary".

Answer (score 0):

Sentences don't have subjects.   Clauses have subjects.   The sentence in question has several clauses.

I / think.   We / need.   They / reverse.   Authorities / say.   What / is.

Consider the following:

> Public health authorities say what is necessary to protect people.

Even this sentence has two clauses.   The simple subject/verb pairing of the matrix clause is *authorites/say*.  The complete direct object of the verb *say* is the content clause *what is necessary to protect people*.

The simple subject/verb pairing of the content clause is *what/is*.   This "what" is sometimes labeled as a *fused relative* because we can substitute a combination of a substantive *that* and a relative *which* to achieve much the same effect: that which is necessary to protect people.

> ... responsive to what public-health authorities say is necessary to protect people

The same subject/verb pairings exist in this transformation.   Here, the fused relative "what" is the topic of the clause, brought forward to mark the entire clause (matrix included) as an available object for the preposition "to".   In turn, that prepositional phrase modifies the adjective "responsive".

The long and involved infinitive phrase "to be more responsive to what public-health authorities say is necessary to protect people" isn't the subject of anything, and it certainly isn't the subject of some clause which it itself contains.   Instead, it expresses the purpose or intent of *reversing course*.